# How to use UserStoppedTypingBehavior from ControlTemplate?

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my .NET MAUI app, I have created a custom search control and ControlTemplate for it. When I'm running the app and perform search the SearchCommand is not getting fired.

If I add the Entry control directly to TestPage and add behavior then its working.

```xml
<Entry Grid.Row="0"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       Placeholder="type here...">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:UserStoppedTypingBehavior
                Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}"
                StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="1000"
                MinimumLengthThreshold="3"
                ShouldDismissKeyboardAutomatically="True" />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

#### Custom control

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents an Entry control styled to contain a search icon
/// and trigger a new search command when the entry text changes.
/// </summary>
public class SearchField : MobileContentViewBase
{
    //Logic of custom control 

    private Entry _searchFieldEntry;
    private const string SearchFieldEntryName = nameof(_searchFieldEntry);

    protected override void AddCustomHandlers()
    {
        if (_searchFieldEntry == null)
        {
            _searchFieldEntry = this.FindChildByClassId<Entry>(SearchFieldEntryName);
        }
    }
}
```

#### App.xaml

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SearchFieldTemplate">
    <StackLayout>
        <ctrls:IconButton
            ImageSource="Search"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent" />

        <Entry
            ClassId="_searchFieldEntry"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:UserStoppedTypingBehavior
                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SearchCommand}"
                    StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="1000"
                    MinimumLengthThreshold="3"
                    ShouldDismissKeyboardAutomatically="True" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="ctrls:SearchField">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Key=SearchFieldTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

#### TestPage.xaml

```xml
<myCtrl:SearchField
    x:Name="searchField"
    Grid.Row="0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Placeholder="Search here..." />
```

#### TestPageViewModel.cs

```cs
public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

public TestPageViewModel()
{
    SearchCommand = new Command<string>(PerformSearch);
}

private void PerformSearch(string searchTerms)
{
    PerformedSearches += $"Performed search for '{searchTerms}'{Environment.NewLine}";
}
```

Instead of simple Binding I have tried TemplateBinding as well with Entry control which is in SearchFieldTemplate but it throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Does anyone know how to make it work? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the BindingContext of the custom control?

Comment: ViewModel of a Page where it will get used.

Comment: Good. Then the binding starts in that viewmodel. So `Path=BindingContext.SearchCommand` isn’t right; that looks in the viewmodel for a property named BindingContext. Try just `SearchCommand`.

Comment: Already tried, it not works.

Comment: Maybe `"{Binding Path=BindingContext.SearchCommand, Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`  But if that works, then `TemplateBinding` should have worked, which you already tried.

Comment: Tried RelativeSource as well but it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviours don't have unique visual tree parents so we cannot use RelativeSource binding on it. You could also refer to this issue: [Relativesource bindings and behaviors](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8584#issuecomment-558153141).

**Workaround**:
Although we cannot use RelativeSource binding for behavior, we could use TemplateBinding for Entry or StackLayout, then refer to it. Consider the code below:

In App.xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="myentry" BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    ClassId="_searchFieldEntry"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:UserStoppedTypingBehavior
            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SearchCommand,Source={x:Reference myentry}}"
            StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="1000"
            MinimumLengthThreshold="3"
            ShouldDismissKeyboardAutomatically="True" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

In the above code, we first use TemplateBinding to set the BindingContext for Entry (`x:Name="myentry"`). Then for Behavior set the Binding Source to the Entry.

Hope it works.

[image]

Comment: This not works if control is used in multiple pages, it works only if used in single page.

Comment: @Divyesh_08  I created a new page with this custom control in it and create a new ViewModel with SearchCommand in it. Set new page's bindingContext to the new ViewModel. Then the command could also fire.

Comment: If you use SearchField in a new page, then  Entry's bindingContext refers to the new SearchField's bindingContext because we use RelativeSource binding for Entry.

Comment: So we should first figure out the bindingContext for the SearchField control. I would appreciate it if you could show more code about other page. How did the custom control place in the new page and what the bindingContext for new page was?

Comment: Create two pages with two viewmodels for each and than add the custom control that you have created. Give it try this way and you will get what I'm saying.

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce. Two new page, two SearchField instance, two corresponding viewModel, worked well on my side. So the difference might be the ```MobileContentViewBase```? Which I don't know exactly it is.

Comment: And seems you pass a CommandParameter which I didn't see in the xaml of behavior.

Comment: no I'm not passing CommandParameter as its not required with UserStoppedTypingBehavior in created command like Command<string>(SearchTriggered);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254021/discussion-between-divyesh-08-and-liqun-shen-msft).

Comment: @Divyesh_08 I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Have you still face the issue? I have added all the code in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254021/discussion-between-divyesh-08-and-liqun-shen-msft). You may have a look.

Comment: I have looked your code, and I'm doing the same.

Comment: That's really weird! Could you tell me what platform, API level and MAUI version you use?

Comment: May I ask if you still meet this issue or not?

Comment: Yes, in the demo it works. For my code I still face issue.

Comment: That's really weird. I think you could reduce the code step by step to find a minimal reproducible example. You could share here if you want and then we could try to figure it out.